# BCFtools fails to read regions inside nested while loop / for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop, vcf-variant-call-format, bcftools

I'm trying to read a file which contains:

```
chr2:1-26910392
chr2:26910393-53820784
chr2:53820785-80731176
chr2:80731177-107641568
```

Then read line per line to filter a vcf file

I'm using

```
count=0
for i in 2; do
    while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((count+=1))
    echo "$i"
    echo "$line"
    echo "$count"
    bcftools view -Oz --regions $line /scratch4/chr"$i"_nsconcat2.ALLChr.vcf.gz > /scratch4/split_contig/split_"$count"_"$i"_nsconcat2.ALLChr.vcf.gz
    done < /scratch4/chr"$i".txt
done
```

I get:

```
Failed to read the regions: chr2:1-26910392
[E::_regions_init_string] Could not parse the region(s): chr2:1-26910392
```

I tried with IFS= and IFS=/n

But when inputing everything manually, it works:

```
 bcftools view -Oz --regions chr2:1-26910392  /scratch4/chr2_nsconcat2.ALLChr.vcf.gz >/scratch4/split_contig/split_0_2_nsconcat2.ALLChr.vcf.gz
```

Echos are working fine and outputting the correct result, so I'm not sure what the problem is

Echo output:

```
2
chr2:1-26910392
0
2
chr2:26910393-53820784
1
2
chr2:53820785-80731176
3
2
chr2:80731177-107641568
4
```

I also observed that when using:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
```

The last line of output runs (chr2:80731177-107641568).
I reverified my txt file and it is composed of one string per line, simply.

Comment: Use `while IFS= read -r line; do`, not `while IFS=\n read -r line; do`.

Comment: Same error, wrapping in quotes ("$line" or ${line} or "${line}" or not, or using IFS= or IFS='' or IFS=\n

Comment: Fix the issues in your code I mentioned plus any others that http://shellcheck.net tells you about and then let us know if you still have a problem.

Comment: Also, check your input file for DOS line endings, see [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `bcftools` so just guessing at this point ... does your `chr*.txt` file contain windows/dos line endings (`\r\n`)? if so, the 1st region would be `chr2:1-26910392\r` and I'm wondering if that could be causing a problem for `bcftools`? (though I'd expect the `\r` to show up in the error messages); if you run one of the following - `od -c chr2.txt` or `echo "$line" | od -c`   - do you see any `\r` references in the output?

Comment: @markp-fuso, 0000000   c   h   r   1   :   1   9   3   6   3   2   7   7   3   -   2
0000020   2   1   2   9   4   5   9   7  \r  \n
0000032
So a trailing dos line ending seems to be the culprit, even tough it is not showing in the error message! How could I solve it?

Comment: See the link I provided.

Comment: I will probably delete my question because it seems to be caused by the dos trailing (never ever header of it, not showing in the error was not helping it). Anyways, do you have any suggestions to create txt files in windows without trailing dos?

Comment: No, sorry, AFAIK if you create a file in Windows you get CRs at the end of each line so if you then want to run a Unix tool on them you often need to remove those CRs. Its an extremely common problem and one of the most frequent causes of questions here.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate! I usually never create txt files in windows but I received these from someone else. Never encountered this problem before. Thanks for the patience

Comment: for this particular case a few quick-n-dirty options: `dos2unix chr2.txt` (updates/modifies file so only have to run once after file is created) `line="${line/$'\r'}"` , `line="${line//$'\r'/}"`, `while read -r line; do .... done < <(tr -d '\r' < chr2.txt)`